# I can't set the top margin of table using css

Tags: html, css, margin

This is so weird;
I have set the margin using CSS of everything to be 0

```
   *{
   margin: 0 0 0 0
   }
```

but there is still space above the table
http://onlinehandytools.com/blah.php?board=EDE&level=AL&subject=biology&year=2009

Comment: `margin: 0;` is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1]** You have three line breaks `<br><br><br>` above the table, remove them and the space will be gone.

**2]** Change `margin:0 0 0 0;` to `margin:0;` and add a `;` after `text-align:center`.

Change This:

```
<h2 style="margin:0 0 0 0;text-align:center">Year: 2009</h2>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="k-grid k-widget">
```

To this:

```
<h2 style="margin:0; text-align:center;">Year: 2009</h2>
<div class="k-grid k-widget">
```

Comment: OMG, I've spent hours trying to figure this out
I'm so stupid
lol, thank you so much :D
oh btw, the colors suck, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: You're welcome. I have no recommendations for the colors, but please mark as correct answer.